# $G$ group, $H \unlhd G$; $gC_G(h) \cap H \ne \emptyset,\forall h \in H,g \in G$ iff $G$ fixes the conjugacy classes of $H$ under conjugation.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have learnt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127644/g-group-h-unlhd-g-prove-disprove-gc-gh-cap-h-ne-emptyset-forall-h/3127840#3127840) that, given a group $G$ and $H \unlhd G$, it is $gC_G(h) \cap H \ne \emptyset,\forall h \in H,g \in G$, if and only if $G$ fixes the conjugacy classes of $H$ under conjugation. Then, it seems that the following holds:

**Corollary.** $K$ a group; put $G:=\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ and $H:=\operatorname{Inn}(K)$; $G$ fixes the conjugacy classes of $H$ under conjugation, and then the above claim holds.

*Proof.* $\operatorname{Inn}(K)=im_\varphi$, where $\varphi \colon K \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(K)$ is defined by $a \mapsto \varphi_a$, being $\varphi_a(g):=a^{-1}ga, \forall g \in K$. Now, $\forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(K)$, $\sigma^{-1}\varphi_a\sigma=\varphi_{\sigma^{-1}(a)}$; but also, $\forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(K)$, $\exists b \in K \mid \sigma^{-1}(a)=\varphi_b^{-1}(a)$. Therefore, $\forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(K)$, $\sigma^{-1}\varphi_a\sigma=\varphi_{\sigma^{-1}(a)}=\varphi_{\varphi_b^{-1}(a)}=\varphi_b^{-1}\varphi_a\varphi_b$, for some $b \in K$. $\blacksquare$

Does this corollary really hold? Is the proof correct?

Comment: It would make it more readable if you included the title within the body of the post.

Comment: I forget the conditions on $n$ so I won't post as an answer, but $S_n$ does not always fix the conjugacy classes of $A_n$ so you should be able to find a counter-example $K=A_n$ for some reasonably small $n$. The mistake in the proof is the existence of $b$ with $\sigma^{-1}(a)=\phi_b^{-1}(a)$ - this seems to be assuming the result that you are trying to prove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just remembered [GroupProps](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A5#Conjugacy_class_structure) gives conjugacy class structure for some small groups, so I will post as an answer.

$S_n$ does not always fix the conjugacy classes of $A_n$. For example if $n=5$ as in the link $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(1,2,3,5,4)$ are in two conjugacy classes of $A_5$ but in the same class of $S_5$. Hence $K=A_5$ is a counterexample.

The mistake in the proof is the existence of $b$ with $\sigma^{-1}(a)=\varphi_b^{-1}(a)$ - this seems to be assuming the result that you are trying to prove.

Comment: I take the chance of your expertise to ask you the following by-question: $\forall h,h' \in H, h'C_G(h) \cap (G \setminus H) \ne \emptyset$ ? Thx

Comment: This is immediately untrue if $H=G$, I'll think a bit more about it though

Comment: so best I can think of is $h'C_G(h)\cap (G\setminus H)\ne\emptyset$ if and only if $h'C_G(H)\not\le H$ if and only if $C_G(H)\not\le H$. So your property holds if and only if, for all $h\in H$ you have $C_G(H)\not\le H$.

Comment: For $G=\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ and $H=\operatorname{Inn}(K)$, your conclusion would sound as: for any given inner automorphism, we can always find an "outer" automorphism that commutes with the former. Am I wrong? If not, could this be helpful in drawing a conclusion?

Comment: I've just reread my comment. Any instance of $C_G(H)$ should be $C_G(h)$. But yes you are correct