# $H \triangleleft G$, $h \in H$. $C_G(h)g \cap H \ne \emptyset, \forall g \in G$ implies $\lbrace C_G(h)g \cap H, g \in G \rbrace$ partition of $H$?

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H \triangleleft G$. I [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127644/g-group-h-unlhd-g-prove-disprove-gc-gh-cap-h-ne-emptyset-forall-h/3127840#3127840)  that 
$G$ fixes the conjugacy classes of $H$ under conjugation if and only if $\forall h \in H, C_G(h)g \cap H \ne \emptyset, \forall g \in G$.

Now, $\forall h \in H$, call $R_g(h):=C_G(h)g \cap H$. I'm arguing that, perhaps under stronger hypothesis than above, $R:=\lbrace R_g(h), g \in G \rbrace$ is a partition of $H$, different than the one induced by conjugacy (namely $O=\lbrace O_h, h \in H \rbrace$, $O_h$ being the orbit by $h$).

Is that it?

Comment: It's not clear what your definition of $R_g$ is. It looks like it's independent of $h$ (not true), so I assume you mean to fix $h$. But then this is trivial, as $\{C_G(h)g|g\in G\}$ partitions $G$ so certainly the intersection with $H$ partitions $H$

Comment: Notation: you're right, I've edited. Induced partition: gosh! I hadn't realized that. Finally, to prove that the induced partition is different from orbits' one, I think it's enough this: $R_g(h) \cap O_h =C_G(h)g \cap O_h \cap H = \lbrace h' \rbrace \cap H = \lbrace h' \rbrace$ (OST), so that $R_g(h)$ and $O_h$ "just cross" each other. Does it fit?

Comment: I don't really follow your notation, I don't think $C_G(h)g\cap O_h$ is always a singleton. But you can see they're different (for $H\ne 1$) by looking at the set containing $1$. We have $O_1=\{1\}$, $1,h\in C_G(h)\cap H$ and if $h=1$ then $H=C_G(h)\cap H$ so in any case the sets containing $1$ in the two partitions are different.

Comment: Right, as a matter of fact, given $h \in H$, $C_G(h)g \cap H \ne \emptyset, \forall g \in G$, simply implies $\exists h' \in H \mid C_G(h)g \cap O_{h'} \ne \emptyset$, and nothing more in terms of "crossings" with orbits. I was then thinking whether we could furtherly constrain $G$ so that, given $h \in H$, $C_G(h)g \cap O_h \ne \emptyset, \forall g \in G$, or even $|C_G(h)g \cap O_h|=1$. But I guess this is another story. Thanks for the provided clarifications so far.